# Unity -I use custom inputfield class have these problems-loss foucs and inspector disable some function~

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to use this custom class but encounter these problems:
1. During execution, this custom Inputfield object loses focus?
    Cannot enter characters in the field
    How to fix it?
2. Why are some functions of the custom inputfield disabled in the Inspector?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3f11.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHWme.gif)

Comment: There is a `Text Component` field, above the `Text` field. It may be disabled because there is no `Text Component` attached, and is `null`. Try to add a `Text Component`, I guess it's `UnityEngine.UI.Text`.

Comment: already  have  Ui.text

Answer (score 0):

You need a structure of `GameObject`s like this

[image: GameObjects]

And in the inspector, drag and drop the `Text` `Component` of the `Text` `GameObject` in the field named `Text Component` of your `CustomInputField` component, as shown below

[image]

You can drag and drop the entire `Text` `GameObject` in the field, it will automatically adds its appropriate component (`Text`)

Otherwise, when you click on the field on screen, there is no text to edit, so nothing happens.